# How to export dataset from sklearn after model applied?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've undertaking a machine learning course with sklearn/python. I understand the preprocessing, selection & running of the model, etc. but now I've ran the data through I'm unsure how to:

- Export this data, OR
- How to find predictions for specific rows (IDs).

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('test_dataset.csv')
dataset.set_index('ID', inplace=True) # replace ID with identifier field
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:-1].values #input variables
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values #output variable (to predict)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 4)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X_train)
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_poly, y_train)

y_pred = regressor.predict(poly_reg.transform(X_test))
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
print(np.concatenate((y_pred.reshape(len(y_pred),1), y_test.reshape(len(y_test),1)),1))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, it will be good if you can ask a specific programming question. Currently you are asking what is done after a model is trained, that is a theoretical question, lot's can be done after a model is trained.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a dataframe using pd.DataFrame and then you can make It a csv file using the method pd.to_csv.
Go through the pandas documentation about these two methods.

Comment: Thanks Akshay, but that does not seem to bring the ID back into it as ID is excluded when assigning X and Y values.

Comment: could you give a link to your test data so i can see the problem more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Option: 1
In this example, if you want to predict on a specific record then you can do something like this

```
some_data_for_predict = dataset[dataset['ID']==1].iloc[:, 0:-1].values
y_pred = regressor.predict(poly_reg.transform(some_data_for_predict))
print(f"actual: \n{dataset[dataset['ID']==1]} \ny_pred: \n{y_pred}")
```

Option: 2
In case there involves preprocessing of data (e.g. handling missing data, applying proper encoding, feature scaling) then probably you will end up with the data encoded after transformation and in such case if you want to see the actuals from the transformed then you can use `inverse_transform`.
Something like:

```
X_normalized = scaler.fit_transform(X)
X_train_norm, X_test_norm, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_normalized, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
some_data = X_test_norm[:5]
regressor.predict(some_data)
scaler.inverse_transform(some_data) # this will give the actual data.
```